# MySQL or PHP syntax oversight when trying to perform conditional update

Tags: php, mysql

I think this is an escaping issue or something.  When I execute the query and populate all variables, everything is peachy and all row is updated properly in the DB.

I looked on StackOverflow to get me rolling with these dynamic/contructed on the fly queries and I'm at the end of my rope.

My stuff looks like this:

```
$sql="UPDATE users SET ";

if (!empty($fname)) { "fname = '$fname', ";}

if (!empty($lname)) { "lname = '$lname', ";}

if (!empty($location)) { "location = '$location', ";}

if (!empty($url)) { "url = '$url', ";}

"WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1";
```

When I break the query to insert the "IFs" I keep getting the following: ***Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1***

I ECHO'd the query and for some odd reason it's nto complete and the variables are coming in before the query start like so

*fname = 'Rob', lname = 'Smith', location = 'Jersey City, NJ', url = 'http://somesite.com', UPDATE users SET* ***Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1***

Sorry if I am not clear.  I will clarify where needed. I am new at all this. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not allowed to have a comma after the last thing you SET.

One easy solution is this:

```
$set = array();
if (!empty($fname)) { $set[] = "fname = '$fname'";}
if (!empty($lname)) { $set[] = "lname = '$lname'";}
if (!empty($location)) { $set[] = "location = '$location'";}
if (!empty($url)) { $set[] = "url = '$url'";}

if(!empty($set)) {
  $sql = "UPDATE users SET ";
  $sql .= implode(', ', $set)
  $sql .= " WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1";
}
```

Oh, and make sure the variables you're shoving in the query are SQL safe; otherwise you've got a SQL injection issue.

Comment: I hate this! you need to we fast to shoot here. this is like 98% of my answer! +1 for you!

Comment: Also, just for the other greenhorns, be sure not to try using that new function "IMPODE"  ;)

Thanks again, Frank

Comment: hah, sorry about the typo.  Corrected impode() to implode() :)

Answer (score 1):

Remember in these programming languages, each statement (text ending with a ;) is much like a complete sentence. You need a subject-object-verb for it to make sense. I can't just say

```
 doggy;
```

I have to say

```
 feed the doggy;
```

Similarly, I can't just say

```
 "fname = '$fname', "
```

when I mean "Append this string to the query I started earlier". I have to be explicit:

```
 $sql .= "fname = '$fname', ";
```

I'm saying "Append this text to $sql". Its a complete sentence.

Comment: I noticed the same thing, but I think that was probably just a transcription error.

Answer (score 1):

better to put all your SETs into an array and implode them into a string. That way you can be sure there are no dangling commas. Something like:

```
if (!empty($fname)) $sets[]="fname = '$fname' ";
if (!empty($lname)) sets[]= "lname = '$lname' ";
if (!empty($location)) sets[]= "location = '$location' ";
if (!empty($url)) sets[]= "url = '$url' ";

$setstring= implode(',',$sets);
if($setstring) {
  $query="UPDATE users SET $sets WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1";
  //run query, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really a direct answer but for dynamic queries i suggest using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). That way you can specify optional parameters more secure, elegant and easier.

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

// insert one row
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();

// insert another row with different values
$name = 'two';
$value = 2;
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

If your queries become larger, the way you are doing things now will be pretty complicated to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

`echo` out your query and take a look at the commas in your SET caluse. Do you have too many? Not enough? I think you'll find that you have one extra comma. You'll probably want to use the `implode()` function to build up your SET clause. This will insert the appropriate number of commas in the appropriate places.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems, there is no space before WHERE which means it could turn out "url=http://www.stackoverflow.com"WHERE" and maybe cause a problem.

Also, there is a comma at the end of every SET clause, the last one in the list should not have a comma.